# variables in jQuery vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in jQuery you have `$variable` and in Javascript you have `variable` without the `$`

Why do you use the `$` if you can just simply declare something as `var variable`? Why do you need to have jQuery `$variables` at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can also have $variable in Javascript. jQuery is just a library that uses`$` to make library and non-library functions easier to distinguish.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement to prefix jQuery variable names with $. It is merely a convention to indicate that the variable is a jQuery object/collection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it and seems terrible to use it like this. You are declaring a variable with the name including the **$** symbol.

Comment: I'd rather say it is personal or team style. Nothing terrible about it at all. It may first look odd, but the benefit is clear: you immediately know this variable references a jQuery object/collection, if this is your or your teams convention, as GregL pointed out. As opposed to a raw DOM element, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

In php we must declare variable with $ sign but in javascript/jquery:

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Thus, there is no convention to use the $ sign as first letter. But the convention is to notify in javascript/jquery the $ sign is for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Its just the naming convention to make you aware whether the variable, that is declared, is a DOM Element or an Object of Elements.

```
var variable = document.getElementById('variable');
```

AND

```
var $variable = $("#variable");
```

Comment: The convention, AFAIK, is to prefix variables storing jQuery collections with $, not strings that jQuery methods like `.html()` return.